# get id before record save to mysql issue

Tags: mysql, max

I want to save properties and images for those properties. While filling out the property form, the user selects images for uploading.

There are two tables: property and images; While saving images I am passing the `propertyid` also.

Runnign a query for MAX(id) gave me 0. The way I am entering it is to increment it by one and save it in images table as prop_id

```
select IFNULL(max(id),0) as id from property
```

I deleted all the data from the property table and now when I save data, I see that `prop_id=1` in the images table and real the `propertyid` in the property table is 11(because 10 records were deleted)...which is clearly an issue.

what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use MAX(id) or similar "magic", you are running into concurrency issues here (i.e. 2 users using the same page at the same time). After insertion use MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID() or the equivalent function in your programming language (mysql_insert_id() in PHP, for example), then use the ID to link your properties to the image.

> i deleted all data from property table now when i save data,i see that
>   prop_id=1 in images table and real property id=11(previously 10
>   records have deleted)...which is clearly an issue.

It is not an issue. You can expect IDs in separate tables to go out of sync eventually; don't fight it. Simply refer from one table to the other, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE property (
  int id primary key auto_increment,

  ... more columns ...
)

CREATE TABLE image (
  int id primary key auto_increment,
  int property_id REFERENCES property(id),

  ... more columns ...
)
```

Or the other way around, depending on your use.

Comment: images table has prop_id not visa versa....i delete 10 records that is why new record will be 11.issue is i am saving images before property which needs propertyid

Comment: Then first save the property, then the image. If, for some reason that is not possible, you have to swap the relation.